# HIGHCHARTS: drilldown.js changes pie chart label color

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am developing a pie chart using Highcharts.
Everything was fine and customized, until I started implementing the Drilldown feature.

This additional JavaScript file is changing the color to #0D2339 of the labels.
My background is almost similar to this color.

I tried changing using

```
dataLabels: {
   enabled: true,
   color: 'white'
}
```

But this did not help.

Comment: Is your Highcharts core file up to date, or an old version?

Comment: Yes, Just checked. Is latest. The custom dataLabel color is being displayed for the drilldown pie.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression will override the color style of `dataLabels` while using **drilldown.js**

```
Highcharts.getOptions().drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle.color = 'white';
```

Note : Make sure the above expression is executed after the external libraries are loaded.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I used this solution to force the hyperlink label to remain white, instead of blue.

Answer (score 0):

Use color code in Hexadecimal format like '#FFFFFF' like

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: '#FFFFFF'
}
```

you can check demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/a2zm449L/

Comment: I tried this too. But as soon as the `drilldown.js` is added, it overrides the styling. As a workaround, i saved the library to my local, and changed the values in it :

`activeDataLabelStyle: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            color: "white",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textDecoration: "underline"
        }`

Comment: Please share drilldown js then.

Comment: You could use this `Highcharts.getOptions().drilldown.activeDataLabelStyle.color = 'white';`

Answer (score 0):

dataLabels works only if we do not use drill down, if we use drill down in our chart then drilldown js overrides dataLabels configuration. Solution is you can use below configuration

```
drilldown: {
          activeAxisLabelStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'none',
            fontStyle: 'regular',
            color:'#ffffff'
          },
    }
```

Comment: Please add some description explaining answer.